# Transaction rollback when performing getByProperty

Tags: google-app-engine, transactions, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

I'm facing a problem that I've been sniffing around for 2 days now and I can't seem to find the solution...

First, my code:

```
Objectify transaction = this.fact().beginTransaction();
myRepo.getByProperty("column_name",proposta.getNumeroPropostaSaude())
...
transaction.put(proposta);
LOGGER.warning("### Chamando transaction.commit"); 
transaction.getTxn().commit();
```

My getByProperty code:

```
public T getByProperty(String propName, Object propValue) {
        Query<T> q = ofy().query(clazz);
        q.filter(propName, propValue);
        return q.get();
    }
```

I get no expection but this log message:

> com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter
>   handleAbandonedTxns: Request completed without committing or rolling
>   back transaction with id -1903971000867716989.  Transaction will be
>   rolled back.

I'm at appengine version 1.9.18 and Objectify v3 (It's an old software...)

The problem started happening out of nowhere, we had no significant change in the code... Any help would be really appreciated.